# How to Clear Adobe reader history programatically using C#

Tags: c#

I need to clear the recently opened documents history from Adobe reader in my windows application using C#.Is it possible?

Comment: Do you know how or where it is saved? Like in a config-file or registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear this registry hive

```
[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\AVGeneral\cRecentFiles]


var registrykeyHKLM = Registry.CurrentUser;
string keyPath = @"Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\10.0\AVGeneral\cRecentFiles";
registrykeyHKLM.DeleteValue(keyPath);
registrykeyHKLM.Close();
```

Comment: if the user has different version of adobe then?

Comment: Well, they should be located in: [-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Acrobat Reader\   make a loop that checks that...